# how can i refer to the current reference when using jquery After()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have multiple divs with the class named **day-number**.  I want to put some text after each instance.  So this works great . .

```
  $('.day-number').after('Put this after');
```

I now need to include something inside the .after() that is the .text() of the .day-number.  How can i refer to the respective instance of .day-number inside the .after() method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.day-number').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var txt = $this.text();
    $this.after('Put this after ' + txt);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Most jQuery DOM manipulation methods accept a function as the parameter, so you can do this:

```
$('.day-number').after(function() {
    return 'Put this after ' + $(this).text();
});
```